# docker swarm create fails when tar can't find container file system

Tags: linux, docker, docker-swarm

I'm running docker on a CentOS VM. Some version information:

Linux cmodqa.lab.c-cor.com 3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 13 10:06:09 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@xxx ~]# docker version
Client version: 1.6.0
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 8aae715/1.6.0
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.6.0
Server API version: 1.18
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 8aae715/1.6.0
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64

Ran this command, as root:

TOKEN=$(docker run --rm swarm create)

Returns:

Timestamp: 2015-05-29 09:26:25.967347311 -0700 PDT
Code: System error

Message: [/usr/bin/tar -cf /var/lib/docker/tmp/c77446605e81944d4fb0d09a68339d2026db2b2af100/_tmp.tar -C /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/c77446605e81944d4fb0d09a68339d2026db2b2afs/tmp .] failed: /usr/bin/tar: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/c77446605e81944d4fb0d09a6cb119e60ff/rootfs/tmp: Cannot chdir: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
: exit status 2

### Frames:

0: setupRootfs
Package: github.com/docker/libcontainer

### File: rootfs_linux.go@30

1: Init
Package: github.com/docker/libcontainer.(*linuxStandardInit)

### File: standard_init_linux.go@52

2: StartInitialization
Package: github.com/docker/libcontainer.(*LinuxFactory)

### File: factory_linux.go@223

3: initializer
Package: github.com/docker/docker/daemon/execdriver/native

### File: init.go@35

4: Init
Package: github.com/docker/docker/pkg/reexec

### File: reexec.go@26

5: main
Package: main

### File: docker.go@29

6: main
Package: runtime

### File: proc.go@63

7: goexit
Package: runtime
File: asm_amd64.s@2232
time="2015-05-29T09:26:27-07:00" level=fatal msg="Error response from daemon: : exit stat

The file system location the tar command is trying to read from doesn't exist:

[root@cmodqa system]# ls -l  /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/c77446605e81944d4fb0d09a68339d2026db2b2af1335a8a6395b1cb119e60ff/rootfs/tmp
ls: cannot access /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/c77446605e81944d4fb0d09a68339d2026db2b2af1335a8a6395b1cb119e60ff/rootfs/tmp: No such file or directory

In fact:

ls -l  /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/c77446605e81944d4fb0d09a68339d2026db2b2af1335a8a6395b1cb119e60ff
total 0

The rootfs for the container doesn't seem to be there. (Does it disappear after the container stops?)

I've run this a few times. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

I did some further digging, on docker's repository on Git.

This is a known issue, apparently based in Red Hat's packaging of Docker, and it effects more than swarm.

A bug was filed with Redhat:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1213258

Use Docker 1.5.0 to work around this situation.